# How to search from a string array in a byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm looking for to search from a string array all the coincidences that could be found inside a byte array, and have these coincidences saved in a text file or so.

So far I have loaded a file and converted its data into byte array. I made a for loop to generate many searches with the length of my byte array.

```
byte[] test = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(openFileDialog1.FileName);

string hex = BitConverter.ToString(test).Replace("-", string.Empty);

for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i++) {
    //String array with some of the patterns I'm looking for in the byte array
    string[] patterns = { "05805A6C", "0580306C", "05801B6C" };

//I get the index if the pattern is found at i position
    int indice = hex.IndexOf("05805A6C", i);
//Do some calculations to get the offset I desire to register
    indice = indice + 8;
    int index = (indice / 2);
//Transform the index into hexadecimal
    string outputHex = int.Parse(index.ToString()).ToString("X");
//Output the index as an hexadecimal offset address
    MessageBox.Show("0x" + outputHex);
// i gets the value of the indice and the loop starts again at this position
    i = indice;
}
```

My method only works for looking at only one pattern. As of now I get all the offset address from the file for the pattern "05805A6C", but I aim to do a full search from the entire patterns array.

How could I go making the same search but considering every pattern on the string array?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. It would help to state the problem you are trying to solve, what you have done to try to solve that problem, and explain what you are trying to do with this sample code.

Comment: You are looking for the array 0x05, 0x80, 0x5A, 0x6C.  So use Array method : int index = Array.BinarySearch(test, compare);

Comment: @jdweng could you elaborate on how to use that method?

Comment: It looks like you're searching for 4-byte patterns. Are you expecting your results to always be aligned to a 4-byte boundary? If so, the code could be simplified a lot

Comment: Also, why `int.Parse(index.ToString()).ToString("X")` instead of just `index.ToString("X")`?

Comment: @jdweng BinarySearch assumes the search pattern is always going to be a 4-byte sequence in ascending order. I think that's just coincidence in the example

Comment: It is no different than using the string IndexOf() method. So use : byte[,] patterns = { {0x05,0x80,0x5A,0x6C}, {0x05,0x80,0x30,0x6C}, {0x05,0x80,0x1B,0x6C} };

Comment: Are the search terms specified in `patterns` fixed forever or do you expect to re-use this algorithm with different inputs?

Comment: Your algorithm will give false positives.  You are string comparing hex, then dividing the result by 2.  Your string match might be at an odd index, in which case the integer division discards the remainder and the data at the new index doesn't match your pattern.

Comment: @jdweng Where are you seeing that `Array.BinarySearch()` will accept a multi-dimensional array as the search term, or that it would work against an unsorted input array?  [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.binarysearch(v=vs.110).aspx) indicates that it only works on Sorted arrays (as with all binary searches).

Comment: I never said it will work against a multi-dimensional array.  You need a for loop (or equivalent like a linq select/where).

Comment: Granted, but `Array.BinarySearch()` will still not work unless all the bytes in the array to be searched were in ascending order, which is not the case for almost all files.

Comment: Wrong, Wrong, Wrong.

Comment: @jdweng Please post an answer with your method rather than giving misinformation in the comments.  `Array.BinarySearch()` does not "search for binary data", it performs a [Binary Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).  It requires a sorted input to give the correct output, and will not work in this case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your intentions correctly. But that is what comes to my mind

```
//String array with some of the patterns I'm looking for in the byte array
string[] patterns = { "05805A6C", "0580306C", "05801B6C" };

foreach (string p in patterns)
{
    int i=0;
    int indice = 0;

    // teminate loop when no more occurrence is found;
    // using a for loop with i++ is probably wrong since
    // it skips one additional character after a found pattern
    while (indice!=-1) 
    {
        // index if the pattern is found AFTER i position, -1 if not
        indice = hex.IndexOf(p, i);

        //Do some calculations to get the offset I desire to register
        i = indice+ 8; // skip the pattern occurrence itself
        int index = (i / 2);

        //Transform the index into hexadecimal
        string outputHex = int.Parse(index.ToString()).ToString("X");

        //Output the index as an hexadecimal offset address
        MessageBox.Show("0x" + outputHex);
    }
}
```

By dealing with the patterns separately you also get a more orderly output. Plus you can define a dedicated method for the single pattern search.

**Edit:** as to your question about ordering (I suppose you mean reorder from greatest to least, right?), change the code like so

```
//String array with some of the patterns I'm looking for in the byte array
string[] patterns = { "05805A6C", "0580306C", "05801B6C" };

foreach (string p in patterns)
{
    List<int> allIndices = new List<int>();

    int i=0;
    int indice = 0;

    // teminate loop when no more occurrence is found;
    // using a for loop with i++ is probably wrong since
    // it skips one additional character after a found pattern
    while (indice!=-1) 
    {
        // index if the pattern is found AFTER i position, -1 if not
        indice = hex.IndexOf(p, i);

        i = indice+ 8; // skip the pattern occurrence itself

        // temporarily store the occured indices
        if (indice != -1) allIndices.Add(i);
    }

    // does what it says :-)
    allIndices.Reverse();

    // separate loop for the output
    foreach (int j in allIndices)
    {
        //Do some calculations to get the offset I desire to register
        int index = (j / 2);

        //Transform the index into hexadecimal
        string outputHex = int.Parse(index.ToString()).ToString("X");

        //Output the index as an hexadecimal offset address
        MessageBox.Show("0x" + outputHex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I intended. It works great. One last thing, though... how could I reorder the offsets from least to greatest?

Comment: @Midori_hige: See my edit at the end of my answer. I hope I did not make a mistake, didn't test it.

Comment: I was hoping to order the entire offsets from every pattern found, ranging from least to greatest. (ex: 0x210, 0x38C, 0x4D8)

Comment: Then I don't understand it, I am afraid. But it sounds like you should invest a little more into reading MSDN on sorting and collections.

Comment: This is not a good approach.  For example, `test = { 0xFF, 0xF0, 0x58, 0x05, 0xA6, 0xCF }` (so `hex = "FFF05805A6CF"`), your algorithm returns `1` when it should return `-1` as there's no byte-wise match.

Comment: This answer is very inefficient.  Nobody would convert a byte[] array to a string for comparison when the are much better array methods to compare byte[] with byte[].

Comment: @jdweng: I did not convert anything into a byte[] array nor did I use byte[] at all. Maybe you mixed something up...

Comment: @Trevor: what the algorithm "should return" depends on the OP's full requirements of the search, which I do not know. I am assuming the OP's original algorithm already had done what he wanted except recognizing multiple patterns. I have modified it to be able to recognize multiple patterns. AND the OP was satisfied with my solution. So what?

Comment: @oliver I wasn't attacking you or your answer, it apparently fits OPs requirements, and that's fine.  However, to make this question more useful to future readers, I had to point out the potential flaws in the OPs approach and therefore the approach of your answer.  Converting byte arrays into hex strings for searching is at best inefficient, and at worst returns returns false positives.

Comment: @Trevor: never mind! You are right in pointing that out. It is a different and valid perspective on the OPs question. People write synthetic code when asking questions. There might be mistakes in it that they might or might not commit in their original code. So we never know for sure whether we should target the foreground problem or also/rather some underlying problems.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't run this against a full battery of test cases, but ...

```
public static class ByteArrayExtensions
{

    public static int IndexOfAny(this byte[] source, byte[][] anyOf)
    {
        return IndexOfAny(source, anyOf, 0);
    }

    public static int IndexOfAny(this byte[] source, byte[][] anyOf, int startIndex)
    {
        var sanitisedAnyOf = new List<byte[]>(anyOf.Where(b => b != null && b.Length > 0 && b.Length <= source.Length));

        if ( startIndex < 0 ) startIndex = 0;

        for ( int i = startIndex ; i < source.Length ; ++ i )
        {
            var testByte = source[i];

            // Check all the anyOf arrays to see if they start a new possible match, and could fit in the remaining data
            for ( int anyOfIndex = 0 ; anyOfIndex < sanitisedAnyOf.Count ; ++ anyOfIndex )
            {
                if ( sanitisedAnyOf[anyOfIndex][0] == testByte && sanitisedAnyOf[anyOfIndex].Length + i <= source.Length )
                {
                    // This is a possible match here, scan forwards to see if it is a complete match
                    int checkScanIndex;
                    for ( checkScanIndex = 0 ; checkScanIndex < sanitisedAnyOf[anyOfIndex].Length ; ++ checkScanIndex )
                    {
                        if ( source[i + checkScanIndex] != sanitisedAnyOf[anyOfIndex][checkScanIndex] )
                        {
                            // It didn't match
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if ( checkScanIndex == sanitisedAnyOf[anyOfIndex].Length )
                    {
                        // This completely matched
                        return i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Test code:

```
void Test()
{
    var anyOf = new byte[][]
    {
        new byte[] { 0xF4, 0xF0 },
        new byte[] { 0x05, 0x80, 0x5A, 0x6C }, 
        new byte[] { 0x05, 0x80, 0x30, 0x6C }, 
        new byte[] { 0x05, 0x80, 0x1B, 0x6C },
        new byte[] { 0x05, 0x05, 0x05, 0x6C },
        new byte[] { },
        new byte[1024]
    };

    var source = new byte[]
    {
        0xF4, 0xF0, 0x58, 0x05, 0xA6, 0xCD, 0x34, 0x05, 0x80, 0xF3, 0x67, 0x5C, 0x05, 0x80, 0x5A, 0x6C, 
        0x58, 0xBF, 0x05, 0x80, 0x5C, 0xFE, 0xB4, 0x8C, 0x05, 0x80, 0x30, 0x05, 0x80, 0x30, 0x6C, 0x77, 
        0x11, 0x70, 0x99, 0xD9, 0xAA, 0xCE, 0x95, 0xDF, 0x17, 0x11, 0x83, 0xCB, 0xF2, 0x0B, 0x73, 0xB8, 
        0x05, 0x05, 0x05, 0x05, 0x05, 0x05, 0x05, 0x05, 0x05, 0x6C, 0x5A, 0x78, 0x05, 0x80, 0x1B, 0x6C
    };

    var matchIndices = new List<int>();
    int matchIndex = -1;
    while ( ( matchIndex = source.IndexOfAny(anyOf, matchIndex + 1) ) >= 0 )
    {
        matchIndices.Add(matchIndex);
    }

    var output = string.Join(", ", matchIndices.Select(i => i.ToString()));
}
```

Which returns:

> output  = 0, 12, 27, 54, 60

This extension method to a byte array adds an `IndexOfAny()` method which takes byte arrays and looks for a match inside the source array.  I believe this will resolve the original question, while fixing a couple of potential issues introduced by comparing as hex.

The issues I have with the string hex comparison are:

- It uses twice as much memory as it needs to store a binary file as hex, and
- It can match a string on a nibble-boundary which isn't a byte-boundary.

For an example of the second case, check `source[1]` to `source[5]`, which contains:

```
{ 0xF0, 0x58, 0x05, 0xA6, 0xCD }.AsHex() => "F05805A6CD"
```

which as hex would incorrectly match the bytes:

```
{ 0x05, 0x80, 0x5A, 0x6C }.AsHex() => "05805A6C"
```

I'm looking for a more efficient method which can process the source data from a stream rather than a byte array.  This would mean that much larger files could be scanned as they wouldn't need to be loaded into memory to be compared.  I had a few issues in my attempt at this with short matches starting later in the array being returned in preference to a longer match that started earlier, but hadn't finished being compared.  For example:

```
var source = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F };
var anyOf = new byte[][]
{
    new byte[] { 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09 },
    new byte[] { 0x05 }
};
```

would return the match on the 0x05 at index 5, rather than the correct match at index 3 which hasn't finished being compared yet.

Hope this helps

Comment: Why are you using byte[][] instead of byte[,]?  Much easier to use byte[,] where you do no have to keep on using "new byte[]".  This code looks ugly.  My solution is much better.

Comment: @jdweng That would assume that every byte sequence that you were searching for would be the same length.  While it appears to be the case in the original question, the extension method can be used generically.  True that if OP was searching for `int`s on 4-byte boundaries, this question would be so much easier.